# C: Hexadecimal output comes out with "ffff"?

Tags: c, hex, output

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int first = cdab3412;

int second = abcd1234;

int result1 = (second >> 16) | (first & 0xFFFF0000);
int result2 = (first << 16) | (second & 0x0000FFFF);

printf("Outputs: %x and %x.\n", result1, result2);
```

result2 turns out as expected an outputs: 34121234

However, result1 outputs ffffabcd. If I just leave it as (first & 0xFFFF0000) it correctly outputs cdab0000.

Why is result1 ffffabcd and not cdababcd?

Comment: 2 suggestions: use `unsigned` variables when shifting, especially right.  Use fixed-width integer type (uint32_t) when using magic numbers like `0xFFFF0000`.

Answer (score 5):

It's called [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension). Set the types to `unsigned int` and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

`second` is a signed integer. So when you shift it to the right the leftmost bit becomes a 1.

If you use `unsigned int's` you'll get the result you expect.

Signed vs. unsigned has always been a source of confusion, so you need to tread carefully.

Comment: If you want to see this drive you crazy change the 'C' in first for a '7' and see it work even with the signed int code (and then see it fail spectacularly in production). I've spent more than a trivial amount of time debugging issues like this one. :)